# How are mentions involving different users with the same username managed?

Tags: support, new-users

I am curious about how mentions involving different users with the same username are managed.

For example, if there's a user called *Joe* and another user called *Joe*, how are they distinguished when you mention them through **@J** ?

Are they shown the same, differently or what? Is just one user notified or both?

Comment: Is it allowed for there to be 2 users who have the username "Joe"?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, names are not unique.

Comment: Yep :(  Just started posting on Seasoned Advice, and realized there's a 31k user there... clearly I will have to change at some point, at least for that site.

Comment: @Joe Why? The system is designed so that people can have the same name. That's not an accident, you're allowed to do so.

Comment: Sure, but it's confusing, particularly when the other user is one of the more highly reputed members of the site.  In answers it's easy to distinguish, but in comments it's not.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The person who commented most recently is always notified if the name reference could work for either.

I do not believe there is any way to contact the other user if they have the *exact same* name. But, if there is a difference such as Joe Bob and Joe Lastname you can do @joeb to specifically contact Joe Bob.

Also:
@J would not notify either since Joe is at least 3 characters long and J is less than three characters long.

You can also read this:
[How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation :-) but what if I want to mention one user who left a comment 5 hours ago but another user with the same username commented 5 seconds ago and isn't the one I want to mention? the same for chat

Comment: Judging from the iine "I do not believe there is any way to contact the other user if they have the exact same name" I don't think there is a way.

Comment: @TomHart Huh, this looks flawed and open to debates if it ever happens. But I know SO goes by the saying *it aint fixed if it's not widely noticed or broken* or a variant thereof.

Comment: @AdamBarak You can make a feature request on meta if you feel strongly enough about it and can provide reasoning for why it should be implemented.

Comment: @Anonymous No, I'm tired and won't post yet another meta request but thanks :-) No, I don't feel so strong about it so leave it at that.

Comment: But it would be helpful to leave a link where someone else can do it. A link where to find the steps to follow may work too.

Comment: @gian1200 What do you mean? Now, after a good sleep I may eager to listen and work, so tell me.

Comment: @ I think this might notify adam barack.  Did it?

Comment: @Yakk It didn't. I had to look myself if there were new comments.

Comment: @[3971020] Maybe this should work?

Comment: @Joe Even this doesn't work :/

Comment: Right, I was using "should" as "should be made to work".

Comment: @Joe [It's been discussed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work#comment387328_43020)

Comment: I'm not meaning unconditional replies, just where it would normally work but there is a name conflict.

Comment: @bob -- does this notify Joe?

Comment: please don't use JoeB as an example!  :)